# How to get back the finished runs of multithreading tcl?

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I'm running simultaneously thoses 2 counters:

```
package require Thread
set TID1 [thread::create -joinable {
 proc DATE {} {clock format [clock scan [exec date]] -format {%m%b%y-%H:%M:%S}}
 puts "start T1-: [DATE]"
 for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i} {
  exec sleep 1
  puts "run T1 $i"
 }
 puts "end T1---: [DATE]"
}]
set TID2 [thread::create -joinable {
 proc DATE {} {clock format [clock scan [exec date]] -format {%m%b%y-%H:%M:%S}}
 puts "start T2-: [DATE]"
 for {set j 0} {$j < 5} {incr j} {
  exec sleep 1
  puts "run T2 $j"
 }
 puts "end T2---: [DATE]"
}]
```

The results are:

```
% tid0x2aeab8e06700
% tid0x2aeab8c05700
% % % % start T2-: 09Sep21-16:03:27
start T1-: 09Sep21-16:03:27
run T2 0
run T1 0
run T2 1
run T1 1
run T2 2
run T1 2
end T1---: 09Sep21-16:03:30
run T2 3
run T2 4
end T2---: 09Sep21-16:03:32
```

How to catch the first finished run (which is T2) and to display it ?,
it doesnt work using the following code:

```
foreach TID {$TID1 $TID2} {
 set FID [thread::join $TID]
 puts "treads finished => $FID"
}
```

Comment: You don't want to `exec` out, (a) for the purposes in your script, (b) from within a Tcl thread. (a) Tcl has equivalents: `after 1000` and `clock seconds`. (b) `exec` means forking in POSIX, and forking from within a thread is not well-behaving. Try avoiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that [Rule 8](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.html#M12) says in part

> Variable substitution is not performed on words enclosed in braces.

You need something that *will* do variable substitution when creating the list that `foreach` iterates over, like

```
foreach TID [list $TID1 $TID2] {
 set FID [thread::join $TID]
 puts "thread finished => $FID"
}
```